# Creating a Qt qml C++ Plugin with CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

I'm trying to create a C++ qml plugin using `cmake` (instead of using `QtCreator`). Here's a dummy project mimicking my plugin setup:

**./CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(circle_plugin)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Qml Quick REQUIRED)

set(HEADERS
    include/Circle.hpp
    include/Plugin.hpp
    )

add_library(circle_plugin STATIC ${HEADERS})

set_target_properties(circle_plugin PROPERTIES AUTOMOC ON)
target_link_libraries(circle_plugin PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Qml Qt5::Quick)
target_include_directories(circle_plugin PUBLIC include)
```

**./include/Circle.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>

namespace test {

class Circle: public QQuickItem {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Circle(QQuickItem* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~Circle() = default;
};

} // namespace test
```

**./include/Plugin.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>

namespace test {

class CirclePlugin : public QQmlExtensionPlugin {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "com.test.CirclePlugin")

public:
    CirclePlugin();
    ~CirclePlugin();

    void registerTypes(const char *uri) {
        Q_ASSERT(uri == QLatin1String("CirclePlugin"));
        qmlRegisterType<Circle>(uri, 1, 0, "Circle");
    }
};

} // namespace test
```

**./qml/View.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import CirclePlugin 1.0

Item {

    Circle {
    }

}
```

I'm linking to `circle_plugin` from my main application. Whenever I `import CirclePlugin 1.0` in my main app's qml files, I get the message `module "Circle" is not installed`.

I've found the following guides on the topic, but I'm still unsure how I can get it working.

[QML Plugin Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-qmlextensionplugins-example.html)

[CMake Maunal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html)

Comment: Where is qml source? Does it include appropriate include?

Comment: I'll update with the qml.

Comment: Ok, I see that qml file is ok. Also you have to put extension library to right path. $QT_INSTALL_QML/Circle or imports/Circle

Comment: Sorry, do you mean in my CMakeLists.txt file, I need to explicitly install the plugin somewhere? Shouldn't cmake take care of that automatically?

Comment: I really don't know how to set up the install proccess with Cmake. As for me I do it with qmake. You can see the example of that in .pro file in on of links in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments in the question, we found out that QtQuick plugins must indeed be installed before being found and used by other QtQuick applications or plugins **<sup>*</sup>**. This means that:

1. The plugin must be in its own project which is composed of **Plugin.hpp** and (at least) a **qmldir** file (assuming that **Plugin.hpp** is built into a plugin library named **libcircleplugin.so**) that looks like:

   ```
   module CirclePlugin
   plugin circleplugin
   ```
2. The plugin (i.e **libcircleplugin.so** and **qmldir**) must be installed inside `QT_ROOT/QT_VERSION/ARCHITECTURE/qml/CirclePlugin/`

Some detailed information about this procedure can be found at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html

Of course, this is all assuming that you use `qmake` with a `circle-plugin.pro` file such as:

```
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += qt c++ nostrip plugin
CONFIG -= android_install #If you care about Android

HEADERS += Plugin.hpp

TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = circleplugin

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = CirclePlugin
qmldir.files = qmldir
OTHER_FILES += qmldir.files

installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \\., /)
qmldir.path = $$installPath
target.path = $$installPath
INSTALLS += target qmldir
```

With this, you can `make install` and your plugin will be found just like any other QtQuick module which are themselves such plugins. This procedure must also be replicated using `cmake` if similar behavior is desired. This requires `QT_INSTALL_QML` to be known which can be queried by executing `qmake -query QT_INSTALL_QML`. **Important note**: This is not a sandboxed approach since it modifies the Qt SDK itself. Be aware that this is evil but also is the current best solution.

---

<sup>* While this is true for Android (see [What is the proper way of deploying C++ QML plugins on mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732537/what-is-the-proper-way-of-deploying-c-qml-plugins-on-mobile-device/25665471#25665471)), a work around is possible on desktop by setting `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` or `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variables to where you installed your plugins (none of which is well documented; in fact, this whole issue is still not well documented to this day). The problem with Android is that the plugin does not get bundled into the apk as long as it is not in `QT_INSTALL_QML` so the final application cannot find the plugin; i.e it must get the same treatment as the other official qml plugins. Manual installation and bundling efforts were fruitless from our side, the plugin was just not found during runtime even if manually forced into the apk (by going as far as writing custom `android-libapplication.so-deployment-settings.json` files per application). A discussion (that went pretty much nowhere beyond `qmake -query QT_INSTALL_QML`) on this topic is in https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-29987. This brings me to my actual point which is below:</sup>

---

### Why should `qmake` be preferred over `cmake` when building Qt plugins/apps?

Although I believe that `cmake` is not only more general but altogether a superior build system to `qmake`, `qmake` still has internals that are sometimes needed (such as `QT_INSTALL_QML`) and is actually **maintained** by Qt for Qt and its applications/plugins. Support for `cmake` for Qt will always be external (and "crippling" as stated by Qt developers themselves). This means potentially more maintenance load in the future on your side as developer, as the solutions to such problems as the above may randomly break with new versions.

I too once dreamed of building my Qt plugins and apps nicely with `cmake` and also maybe cross-compiling them with `.toolchain.cmake`'s like https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake. I quickly found out that it is simply not worth doing.

Comment: "Support for cmake for Qt will always be external" — well, that didn't age like a wine. CMake is currently being officially supported by Qt, while qmake is decaying on a minimal life support.